# on raw reaction add throws an error: discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I was working on an "self-reaction" script for my discord bot, so I was using `on_reaction_add()` and it worked fine, but I realized that as I restarted my bot, he couldn't register the reactions on that first message, so I did some research and I figured out that I had to use `on_raw_reaction_add()` I tried it and I worked fine, but the last line of code threw an error:

```
@Client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.user_id == Client.user.id:
        return

    if str(payload.emoji) == "" and payload.channel_id == 1078702317386524170:
        guild =Client.get_guild(1075533700804530239)
        role = guild.get_role(1078715150363795417)
        await discord.User(payload.user_id).add_roles(role)
```

Error:
`TypeError: BaseUser.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`
Whole Error: [here](https://pastebin.com/4G1ji2Fm)

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to instantiate a `discord.User` yourself. You've already gotten the `guild`, let's use `get_member` to get the user so we can add the role.

```py
@Client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.user_id == Client.user.id:
        return

    if str(payload.emoji) == "" and payload.channel_id == 1078702317386524170:
        guild = Client.get_guild(1075533700804530239)
        role = guild.get_role(1078715150363795417)
        user = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        if not user:
            # incase they are not cached
            user = await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id)
        await user.add_roles(role)
```